# How to resize FormFile image and save to "/public/images/" folder in GoFiber

Tags: go, go-fiber

I am using Gofiber as a RestAPI. I send a post request with a FormData format to the Gofiber server.

```
file,fileError := c.FormFile("image")
```

But from this file, I cannot resize that file. How can I resize and save that file to my folder?

Answer (score -1):

```
file, fileError := c.FormFile("image")
uniqueId := uuid.New()
filename := strings.Replace(uniqueId.String(), "-", "", -1)
fileExt := strings.Split(file.Filename, ".")[1]
imageName := fmt.Sprintf("%s.%s", filename, fileExt)
img, _ := file.Open()
CusImage, errImg := jpeg.Decode(img)
if errImg != nil {
    return errImg
}
m := resize.Resize(945, 410, CusImage, resize.Lanczos3)
out, errCreate := os.Create(fmt.Sprintf("./public/images/%s",imageName))
if errCreate != nil {
    return errCreate
}
defer out.Close()
jpeg.Encode(out, m, nil)
```